# multiple images repeatedly fading in ant out

Tags: fadein, fadeout

I wasn't sure how to ask this. Can [this effect](http://www.essexllp.com/) be achieved by putting each of the 6 images in separate divs or li (list) and adding fadein/fadeout?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [here](http://jqueryui.com/effect/#default) ? I love [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedResponsiveImageGrid/index5.html).

Jquery UI library enough for effects.